# Database is locked

Tags: database, sqlite

hey my problem is when i try to update my database it goes through the update query fine but then it crashes giving me a error in the console saying "Error while updating 'Database is locked'". Does any one have a clue why is it so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually because your database is in another transaction. For example, if you have another thread going or another connection and it is in a transaction.

Comment: yaa you were right. Actually i had opened my database in several methods but dint close it. Dat was the catch.

Answer (score 0):

closing the rails console session resolved this issue for me.

Comment: of course, i thought for some reason that this was Rails specific question. my bad.